# Methods to set general form settings

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I use google script to generate forms (to manage a soccer team).

This script do :

1. Generate a forms
2. Generate a shared URL
3. Send mail in a google groups mail.

All is ok but i've missing parameters. I'me searching the equal of these 3 last parameters : 
[image: Screenshot respondents]

Anyone can help me please ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Please see documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form

- Collect email address: setCollectEmail(collect)
- Requires sign-in: setRequireLogin(requireLogin)
- Respondents can: setPublishingSummary(enabled)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.

I was in in "FormResponse" class instead "From" class.

Closed subject

Comment: @Biche_XD If this helped you identify the correct class please consider accepting this as an answer. Many thanks.