# Google Forms API make form private

Tags: google-drive-api, google-forms, google-forms-api

I need to create a Google Form programmatically and limit the emails/accounts that can access it.

Using the Web UI is possible to limit the access to accounts that belong to the same organisation (which is not perfect but is better than being public), but I'm unable to create a form using the API with that option enabled.

The Google Forms API documentation doesn't mention anything related with access restrictions.
I know the form will be stored in Google Drive, but the permissions there seem to be correct.

Using the google APIS, is there a way to limit the access to a form to specific emails? Or if that is not possible, how do I restrict the access to only allow accounts from the same organisation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Methods to set general form settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381779/methods-to-set-general-form-settings)

Comment: I'm using the google forms REST api and not Google App Scripts but I will check if it helps with my problem. ty

Answer (score 0):

Use Forms Service from Google Apps Script, more specifically `FormsApp.Form.setCollectEmail(true)` and `FormsApp.Form.setRequireLogin(true)` as the Forms REST API isn't able isn't able to handle most of the Form settings, it only handle the quiz settings.

---

The Google Forms API doesn't cover all the Google Forms features, actually https://developers.google.com/forms used to explain what things could be done with the Google Apps Script Forms service and what could be done with the Google Forms REST API. I don't know why Google removed this content.

Unfortunatelly there are some settings that aren't available on none of them.

---

References

- https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setcollectemailcollect
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setRequireLogin(Boolean)